# How to change encoding of EMF model instances from ASCII to UTF-8 in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, text, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I am on working most of the time on Mac. I have changed the "Text file encoding" of my Eclipse instance from "Properties->Workspace" to UTF-8. But still, when I create EMF model instances (be it dynamic or from registered examples), the created *.xmi-files have always "ASCII" as their encoding. When I try to share these project containing the models, instances etc. over SVN, this causes some problems if I work with these later on a Windows machine. It is probably a Windows problem regarding the SVN. The exact error code can a later post here.

Still, from now on, I would like to work with UTF-8 anyways. So the question is, why are my created text files still encoded in ASCII, even though my Eclipse workspace property has been set to UTF-8?

I have also tried to change the property globally within eclipse.in with the following line: *-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8*

Another thing I was wondering, if the "New text file line delimiter" from "Properties->Workspace" set to default (in my case Unix) could have anything to do with this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an XML resource, the following might help:

[XMLResource JavaDoc](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.7.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/xmi/XMLResource.html#setEncoding%28java.lang.String%29)

-Martin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.